# PHP can't create a socket to a java server on the same subnet

Tags: java, php, apache, sockets, xampp

First of all I want to thank you for reading this question.

Previously I worked with a java server and an apache server (which is provided by xampp) on the same system. 
Although this method isn't ideal at all, it worked.

I transferred the java server to another system, which is running openSuse.
Both systems run on the same subnet. After setting everything up, the apache server (on system A) couldn't connect to the java server (on system B).

- I checked with nmap of the port that is used by java is open and it is.
- I also created a java socket on system A and tried to connect to the
  server on system B, then I get an error on system A that the
  connection has been timed out and on system B happens nothing.
- As a result of the previous test I changed the timeout to 1000ms. You
  can guess what happened. Yeah the same as before.

**The php code**

```
$address = '192.168.11.30';
$port = 4567;

$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_bind($socket, $address, $port);
socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

socket_write($socket, "hello world \n");
socket_close($socket);
```

I hope I provided enough information, if you need more or different information, I'll also provide that.

Kind regards

Comment: Are you sure you're not running a firewall on either A or B?

Comment: @SanderBackus I doubt it, but I will check it again and let you know

Comment: @SanderBackus I disabled my entire firewall in openSuse and now it is working but when I enable it and add an exception for the port I need, it fails again